# Update Counter Value Through All Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, apple-push-notifications

Currently, working on IOS push notification, I want to maintain the badge count between multiple threads. Their are n numbers of threads and each thread have the copy of the counter, thread 1 have counter value 4, thread2 counter may have value 6, all these threads send information to the APNS, this results wrong batch count or counter on the IOS device.

How can I sync the updated value of the counter between all threads, if the latest count is 30, all respective threads counts get update to 30, so the information remains consistent.

Below is the code.

```
    new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            pushNotification.SendIOSPushNotification();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Util.LogElmahError(ex);
        }
    }).Start();
    return userdevices;
}

public void SendIOSPushNotification()
{
    // Count increased in sequential order and shared between multiple threads,
    // how we can maintain the updated state between all the threads.
    // UnreadCount
    unreadcount = DatabaseCall();
    // Send information to APNS
    apnsBroker.QueueNotification(new ApnsNotification
    {
        DeviceToken = token.AuthToken,
        Payload = JObject.Parse(
            "{\"aps\":{\"badge\":" + UnreadCount.MessageID + ",\"alert\":" +
            jsonAlert + ",\"sound\":\"sound.caf\"},\"jsoncontent\":" + jsonContent + "}")
    });
}
```

Comment: Try looking up `Interlocked.Add`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use volatile modifier to deal with such scenario.

> The volatile modifier is usually used for a field that is accessed by
>   multiple threads without using the lock statement to serialize access.
>   Using the volatile modifier ensures that one thread retrieves the most
>   up-to-date value written by another thread.

Comment: How this will help me my counter information is retrieved from database, how can I use the above information with this case.

Answer (score 0):

volatile modifier is a solution, however, you may use [`Interlocked` static methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked_methods.aspx) for adding and reading the values:

```
var localCount = DatabaseCall();
Interlocked.Add(ref unreadcount, localCount);
```

[Read from a `int` variable are atomic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691278.aspx), but you still need to mark the field as `volatile`. For `long` value reading you can use

```
var allCount = Interlocked.Read(ref unreadcountLong);
```